# Cognos SQL _last_day_of_month

Tags: sql, date, cognos, cognos-11

I would like to find the last day of a month with Cognos SQL. When I use the function in Cognos I just get an error message, although the date format is correct (e.g. 2023-02-14).

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

[image: Cognos SQL Code]

Comment: Please post your code and the error message as text - not an image.  That will help the next person who searches for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The _last_of_month function expects a date data type and you are passing it a string. You will need to cast the string to a date.  Additionally syntactically you have too many closing brackets.